# create new df from existing df in pandas - python

Tags: python, pandas

What should be the optimized pandas command to create a new data frame from existing data frame that have only 1 column named **val** with the following transformation.

Input:

```
1_2_3
1_2_3_4
1_2_3_4_5
```

Output:

```
2
2_3
2_3_4
```

Remove everything till first underscore (including _) and also remove everything after last _ (including  _)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas.Series.str.replace) with a regex that matches characters up to and including the first `_` and from the last `_` to the end of string, replacing both those parts with nothing:

```py
df['val'] = df['val'].str.replace('^[^_]*_(.*)_[^_]*$', r'\1')
```

Output:

```
     val
0      2
1    2_3
2  2_3_4
```

If you want that single column in a new dataframe, you can convert it to one using [`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```py
df2 = df['val'].str.replace('^[^_]*_(.*)_[^_]*$', r'\1').to_frame()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way with str slicing after split:

```
df['val'].str.split("_").str[1:-1].str.join("_")

0        2
1      2_3
2    2_3_4
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the string by the charcters between start of string r1 and r2 end of string

where `r1=digit_` and `r2=_digit`

```
df.a.str.split('(?<=^\d\_)(.*?)(?=\_\d+$)').str[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the first and the last `_` using `str.find` and `str.rfind` and then you can get the substring from it.

```
df['val'] = [x[x.find('_')+1:x.rfind('_')] for x in df['val']]
```

Output:

```
     val
0      2
1    2_3
2  2_3_4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) method

```
df.vals = df.vals.str.replace(r'^1_', '').str.replace(r'_\d$', '')
```

I'm passing 2 regex, first one finds the substring 1_ and replaces it with empty string, the second one finds substrings with an underscore followed by a number at the end of the string (That's what the '$' means) with an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Regex-related questions are always fun.

I'll throw one more to the mix. Here's `str.extract`:

```
df['new_val'] = df['val'].str.extract('_(.+)_')
```

Output:

```
         val  new_val
0      1_2_3        2
1    1_2_3_4      2_3
2  1_2_3_4_5    2_3_4
```